# How can I inner join two tables?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]
[image]

Hi ! Anyone can tell me what's wrong with my jointure?
Thank you very much!

```
SELECT 
country_code,
country_name,
year,
crude_birth_rate,
crude_death_rate

FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_international.country_names_area`as Country_name_area
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_international.birth_death_growth_rates` as birth_death_growth_rates

ON birth_death_growth_rates.country_code = Country_name_area.country_code;
```

Comment: _what's wrong with my jointure?...._ What issues/errors are you facing?

Comment: It's not country_nameS_area?

Comment: When several tables are involved it's good programming practice to qualify _all_ column names. E.g. `Country_name_area.country_code` instead of just `country_code`. (Even in the select list.)

Comment: @jarlh Perfect ! thank you so much,that made it work amazing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer columns with alias of tables:

```
SELECT 
Country_name_area.country_code,
Country_name_area.country_name,
birth_death_growth_rates.year,
birth_death_growth_rates.crude_birth_rate,
birth_death_growth_rates.crude_death_rate

FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_international.country_names_area`as Country_name_area
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_international.birth_death_growth_rates` as birth_death_growth_rates

ON birth_death_growth_rates.country_code = Country_name_area.country_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this :

1. You have to add alias for table & use into select column statements and join.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the query, the error message is pretty clear:

> Error: Column name country_code is ambiguous at [2:1]

You should learn to read the error messages; BQ is pretty good at explaining issues in queries.

The column `country_code` is in both tables.  As mentioned in other answers, you want to *qualify* all column references.  I want to point out that simpler table aliases makes the query easier to write and read.

You can also use `USING`, because the `JOIN` keys have the same name:

```
SELECT country_code, cna.country_name, bdgr.year,
       bdgr.crude_birth_rate, bdgr.crude_death_rate
FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_international.country_names_area` cna JOIN
     `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_international.birth_death_growth_rates` bdgr
     USING (country_code);
```